# Find directories created less than a week ago

Tags: bash, unix, find

I know I can use this command to find directories **created or modified** less than a week ago:

```
find /home -type d -mtime -7
```

But how do I find directory that were **created** less than a week ago?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Creation time is **not** stored.

There is only 3 timestamps you can check

```
Last access time
Last modification time
Last change time
```

"Change" is one of: permission changes, rename etc. 
While the modification is contents only.

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: you can't.

There are three times stored in an inode

- ctime: time of creation or change of the inode
- mtime: time of last change of the file that the inode refers to
- atime: time of last access to the file

The point is: ctime is altered not only by create, but also by chmod / chown, maybe even by ln (not sure). `Man stat` and `man touch` are your friends.

If you try to find fresh directories by means of `find /home -type d -mtime -7` be prepared to also find older directories that had their mode or owner changed.