# shell script to find only the list of all folders created in last n minutes

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ls

I want to list all folders inside a folder, created in last n minutes. It should not include the sub folders inside a folder.
I tried the following which did not worked

```
ls   -d  * | find -cmin -60
```

Please suggest some way

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find directories created less than a week ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465433/find-directories-created-less-than-a-week-ago)

Comment: Note that `find` does not read its standard input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

e.g.:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -cmin -60 -print | egrep -v '^(\.|\.\.)$' | sed 's/..//'
```

will find all directories and don't go to sub-dirs, and exclude `.` and `..`

EDIT: now will print instead of `./dir` only `dir`

alternatively,

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -cmin -60 -printf "%f\n" | egrep -v '^(\.|\.\.)$'
```

Comment: thanks ... but it's including . symbols, like ./result ./dir etc . for me only the dir names are needed like result dir

Comment: i think i can cut the first two characters from the result to get the list of only the directory names ...

Comment: add to your question - exactly WHAT you have and WAHT you want. Edited the answer to cut first two characters

Comment: only the directory names those are created in last n minutes inside a directory so that i can make some db query using the folder names, as the reply suggested by you contains "./ " before the dir name it can not be used so i  think i can cut the first two characters from the result to get the list of only the directory names

Comment: thnks few modifications to your second answer is working for me :) voted for you

Comment: +1 and you can avoid using `egrep` with the `-mindepth` option like this: `find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -cmin -60 -printf "%f\n"`

Comment: yes yes ... I tried that which gave me the correct result, thats why i mentioned as after few modifications I got the right answer.. thanks to you

Answer (score 3):

It's easier to do

> find . -type d -cmin -60 -print

Comment: this is printing the directories inside the parent directory which is the problem, please suggest some way not to print child directory contained by the parent directory

Comment: @Tarai use the `-maxdepth 1` option to only find stuff in the current directory